# adding subdistrict to magento 2 checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am adding subdistrict to magento 2 checkout page on address form. In magento 1 i used ajax to get the subdistrict for the selected city.
How to do this to comply with magento 2 best practice?

Comment: Is `subdistrict` to be your custom address attribute?

Comment: subdistrict is taken from a new table 'directory_city_subdistrict' and the value will be saved to order address